# How To Find the Integral of e When the Exponent Has Multiple Variables

Tags: calculus

My calculus class just started going over "Separation of Variables" where you have something like $\frac{dy}{dx} = x$ and have to solve for $y$.

I understand that to do this, one must get dx on one side and dy on the other, and then take the integral of both sides. Tonight I was assigned some homework problems, one of which looked like this:

$\frac{dr}{ds} = e^{r-2s}$
I turned this into:
$r = \int e^{r-2s} ds$

However once I get to this step I am unsure of how to go further. I was thinking I would turn it into this:

$-\frac{1}{2} \int 2e^{r-2s} ds$

But I don't know how to find the integral of the e considering the fact that there are two variables in the exponent. Can anyone give me any info/tips on this topic?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the tip. I just joined this so I am still figuring things out.

Comment: I just edited my post to give more information, does it look better know?

Comment: $$\mathrm{e}^{r-2s} = \mathrm{e}^r\mathrm{e}^{-2s} = \frac{\mathrm{e}^r}{\mathrm{e}^{2s}}\text{.}$$

Comment: @EricTowers this makes sense in terms of breaking it down but I'm still unsure of how to solve the integral. Do I only go through the +1 to the exponent and divide process for the s because it is ds?

Comment: Move everything containing "$s$"s (including exponentials and differentials) to one side and everything containing "$r$"s to the other side.  Then integrate.

Comment: @Jack Better...but you should type Mathjax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Oh, I forgot that I could still do that. That makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Wolgwang I will check that out. Thank you.

Comment: So the answer to the question literally asked in the title is: you don't. But I think you got a couple of good tips in the comments anyway!

Comment: Yeah, I was able to use these tips and then some outside research to figure it out in the end.

Comment: @Jack: you can [post an answer to your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). It might then be helpful to others.